# PivotViewer alternative for WPF

Tags: wpf, pivotviewer

Is there any control for WPF that works like the [PivotViewer for Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/pivotviewer/), free or commercial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. However there is a HTML5 version that can be found over at CodePlex : http://lobsterpothtml5pv.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. I found that too while googling but I was hoping for a pure WPF alternative.

Answer (score 1):

there's a mention here of WPF PivotViewer application: https://twitter.com/RickRat/status/21812745309528064
and you can download some demo .net-based application from the link posted there (no source code in the .zip, didn't run the app) that seems to use MVVMLight judging from the assemblies (DLLs)

You could use a WebBrowser control and host Silverlight with PivotViewer in it. Then talk to it via the HTML bridge of Silverlight

Alternative is to use HTML5 PivotViewer (again via the WebBrowser control) in your WPF app

would be nice to have a portable version of PivotViewer indeed, very powerful tool (I use it at http://gallery.clipflair.net)

Apart from LobsterPot's HTML5 PivotViewer and its older free version (see related links at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hrhtraih5gzqj9w/AAB2n18GAPWJW_hZVdz-tmW0a?dl=0), for another HTML5 PivotViewer you could host that comes from former SeaDragon team members at Microsoft and seems to work very well see"

http://seajax.github.io/

https://github.com/seajax/seajax/tree/master/v2/app/pivot

https://github.com/seajax/seajax/blob/master/v2/app/pivot/quickstart.html

https://github.com/seajax/seajax

Note that the WebBrowser control uses IE7 or something as HTML engine by default and you need some meta markup at the top of your HTML to tell it to use Edge mode - the latest IE engine that is installed)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```